# Toggle conditionals in lstlisting escapes

Tags: listings, conditionals

I'm looking for a way to toggle conditionals inside `lstlisting` escapes.

MWE: I expect this

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapechar=\%}

\newif\ifa
\newcommand\x{\ifa a \else b \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
%\atrue%
x := %\x%
%\afalse%
x := %\x%
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

to output

```
x := a
x := b
```

Instead, I get

```
x := b
x := b
```

The same happens for similar code using `etoolbox` toggles.

Comment: The `listings` documentation mentions

"You might use \def, \edef, etc., [inside escapes] but do not assume that the definitions are present later, unless they are \global."

If that's the reason for the conditionals not working, I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned you can use `\global`.

[image: global]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapechar=\%}

\newif\ifa
\newcommand\x{\ifa a \else b \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
%\global\atrue%
x := %\x%
%\global\afalse%
x := %\x%
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```